# BSOD in Windows when sharing Firefox profile across partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, bsod

I've a grub-run dual-boot (Ubuntu 16.04 & Windows 7) with a third, 25GB, NTFS partition shared between the two. I'm attempting to use the same Firefox profile with Ubuntu and Windows, located on the shared partition (so all the addons, favorites, etc. will be kept). It works fine for Ubuntu, and works well for Windows *at first*, but, upon using this profile on Windows, when I restart the computer and try to log back into Windows, a BSOD flashes during the "Starting Windows" splash screen.

I have to restore the computer to an earlier date before I can get in (Ubuntu consistently works fine through out, though).

Unfortunately, it flashes too quickly for me to see anything, and there are no minidumps stored in the Event Viewer or anything like this.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on, or methods of further troubleshooting this issue? (P.S. - I don't want to use Firefox Sync.)

**EDIT:** I was able to take a picture of the BSOD. It's a 0x0000007e error and the problem file is "IaStorv.sys"

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Fast Startup enabled then disable that.  In a dual-boot situation it can lead to data loss, or issues, on the Windows side.

Right click on your Start button in Windows, choose Control Panel, choose Power Options in the icons view, choose choose what the power buttons do, choose change setting that are currently unavailable, uncheck fast startup.

Comment: Weird. When I click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable," the link just disappears and nothing happens.

Comment: I edited the original post with some error information if that helps at all.

Comment: Do you have Hibernate disabled?  If hibernation is disabled then it disables fast startup with it.

Comment: I do, yeah. ---

Comment: Wait a minute, I'm an idiot, Fast Startup is a Windows 10 feature.  I totally missed you are running 7.  Sorry.

Comment: Ah! No worries.